# how to get fields list of view fields from SPSiteItemCollection

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, caml, spquery

I want to get fields list of SPSiteItemCollection that limited by SPQuery view fields. for example I limited the view field which CAML query like this:

```
spQuery.ViewFields="<FieldRef ='TestFieldName' />";
```

and I executed query with this code and `splist.GetItem(spQuery)` passed the result to another function and now I want to get current view fields list in this context I expect to get "TestFieldName" but I don't know how.
I know I can find all fields list with codes like this:

```
List<SPField> fields=listItem.Fields.Cast<SPField>().ToList();
```

or geting specific view by this code:

```
List<SPField> fields=list.Views["ViewName"].Fields.Cast<SPField>().ToList();
```

**My question is:** how can I get fields list of specific SPQuery view field?

Answer (score 0):

have you try to use the [ViewFieldsOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfieldsonly) ?
It should return only the fields specified in the query

```
spQuery.ViewFields="<FieldRef ='TestFieldName' />";
spQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```